# AngularJS - Change the content of an image dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change dynamically the images of a slide changing the `src` attribute. The code does execute, but on my page nothing appears instead of my old slide. The `src` attribute is set correctly but no errors shows.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="catalogue">
    <div class="lineaCatalogo" ng-repeat="linea in lineas">
      <img ng-src="{{linea.image}}" alt="">
      <h3 ng-click="getLinea(linea)">{{linea.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{linea.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="productPartial" ng-repeat="linea in lineas | filter: {title: selected_linea_title}">

    <div id="banner-fade1">
      <ul class="bjqs">
        <li ng-repeat="producto in linea.productos" id="{{producto.title}}"><img src="{{producto.image}}" title="{{producto.description}}"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="datosProducto" ng-repeat="producto in linea.productos | filter: {title: 'Producto 2'}">
      <h2 class="tituloProducto">{{producto.title}}</h2>

      <p class="descripcionProducto">{{producto.description}}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And JS code:

```
$scope.selected_linea_title = 'Linea 3';
    $scope.selected_linea;
    $scope.selectedProduct = 'Producto 1';
    $scope.getLinea = function(linea){
        $filter
        $scope.selected_linea_title = linea.title;
        $scope.selected_linea = linea;
    }
```

`getLinea()` gets a hash object and selects the one I clicked on #catalogue

And the data:

```
$scope.lineas = [
    {
        title: 'Linea 1',
        description: 'Descripcion 1',
        image: 'img/linea3-3-g.jpg',
        productos: [
        {
            title: 'Producto 1',
            description: 'The description of the first product. It is not important to see the quality, just the maximum length we can show at the end.',
            image: 'img/linea1.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Producto 2',
            description: 'The description of the second product. It is not important to see the quality, just the maximum length we can show at the end.',
            image: 'img/linea1.jpg'
        },
        {
            title: 'Producto 3',
            description: 'The description of the third product. It is not important to see the quality, just the maximum length we can show at the end.',
            image: 'img/linea1.jpg'
        }
        ]
    },
```

EDIT: I found out the next error:

file:///C:/Users/Jose/Raul/webUM/%7B%7Bproducto.image%7D%7D Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Why is not accepting the {{}} symbols??

Comment: Use ng-switch in html view.

Comment: Please reduce your example to a minimum, so that we don't have to read the whole unrelated source code. Also try to provide a plnkr

Comment: I tried to use the plnkr but I think this is quicker:

https://github.com/Raulvv/webUM